# javascript jquery radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 radio buttons and jquery running.

```
<input type="radio" name="lom" value="1" checked> first
<input type="radio" name="lom" value="2"> second
```

Now, with a button I can set onClick to run a function.  What is the way to make radio buttons run a function when I click on one of them?

Comment: Note. It's best not to have form elements respond to click, as many people navigate forms using the keyboard.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can use `.change` for what you want

```
$("input[@name='lom']").change(function(){
    // Do something interesting here
});
```

**as of jQuery 1.3**

you no longer need the '@'. Correct way to select is:

```
$("input[name='lom']")
```

Comment: Note that, as of jQuery 1.3, you no longer need the '@'.  Correct way to select is: `$("input[name='lom']")`

Comment: Is it possible to integrate this solution with @JohnIdol 's solution below with conditional statements based on radio values?  ex `$("input[name='lom']").change(function(){ if ($(this).val() === '1') {..... // rest conditional statements based on values here } ;`

Comment: As of jQuery 1.3, you **should not** use '@' with the name property. If you do so, you will get an `jquery.self-0a6570c….js?body=1:1464 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression` error. So it's not a matter of choice.

Answer (score 60):

If you have your radios in a container with id = radioButtonContainerId you can still use onClick and then check which one is selected and accordingly run some functions:

```
$('#radioButtonContainerId input:radio').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
      myFunction();
    } else if ($(this).val() === '2') {
      myOtherFunction();
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me, because my field was part of an array and I couldn't use the input[name='xxx'] notation - <input type="radio" name="Need[measure_type]" id="Need_measure_type" value="aaa">

Comment: Does this react even if you tab down and move the marker with arrowkeys?

Comment: this won't work in mobile # selector is not working in mobile.

Answer (score 21):

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="creditcard" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="cash"/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="cheque"/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="instore"/>

$("input[name='radio']:checked").val()
```

Comment: Although this answer does not show how to wire up the code to the event, I like it that it contained the info for how to retrieve the value of the radio button group.

Comment: $("input[@name='lom']").change(function(){
    // Do something interesting here
});

Answer (score 15):

this should be good

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
       alert('ole');
    });
});
```

Comment: You have missed a ); at the back.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do this. Having a container around the radio buttons is highly recommended regardless, but you can also put a class directly on the buttons. With this HTML:

```
<ul id="shapeList" class="radioList">
<li><label>Shape:</label></li>
<li><input id="shapeList_0" class="shapeButton" type="radio" value="Circular" name="shapeList" /><label for="shapeList_0">Circular</label></li>
<li><input id="shapeList_1" class="shapeButton" type="radio" value="Rectangular" name="shapeList" /><label for="shapeList_1">Rectangular</label></li>
</ul>
```

you can select by class:

```
$(".shapeButton").click(SetShape);
```

or select by container ID:

```
$("#shapeList").click(SetShape);
```

In either case, the event will trigger on clicking either the radio button or the label for it, though oddly in the latter case (Selecting by "#shapeList"), clicking on the label will trigger the click function twice for some reason, at least in FireFox; selecting by class won't do that.

SetShape is a function, and looks like this:

```
function SetShape() {
    var Shape = $('.shapeButton:checked').val();
//dostuff
}
```

This way, you can have labels on your buttons, and can have multiple radio button lists on the same page that do different things. You can even have each individual button in the same list do different things by setting up different behavior in SetShape() based on the button's value.

Answer (score 3):

it is always good to restrict the DOM search. so better to use a parent also, so that the entire DOM won't be traversed.

> **IT IS VERY FAST**

```
<div id="radioBtnDiv">
  <input name="myButton" type="radio" class="radioClass" value="manual" checked="checked"/>
 <input name="myButton" type="radio" class="radioClass" value="auto" checked="checked"/>
</div>



 $("input[name='myButton']",$('#radioBtnDiv')).change(
    function(e)
    {
        // your stuffs go here
    });
```