# Text display on radio button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to make a script function which displays text when the user clicks on radio buttons to choose his/her gender. So when the user clicks on female, the text 'hello ma'am' appears, and when Male is clicked, 'Hello sir' is returned. Any suggestions are highly appreciated :)

I have used this script:

```
    <script>          
function myFunction() {                
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<label for="gender"><b>Gender</b></label>
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="gender" value="male" onclick="myFunction()">Male
    <p id="text" style="display:none">Hello sir :)</p>


    <input type="radio" id="myCheck" name="gender" value="female" onclick="myFunction()">Female
    <p id="text" style="display:none">Hello ma'am :)</p>
```

But only one of them works, for instance in this case, only when Male is pressed since it's the first one written in the code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142300/javascript-jquery-radio-button-click) might help you

Comment: `id`s must be unique in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an on change event. This code snippet should help you out.

```js
$('input[name="gender"]').change(function() {
  alert("Hello " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Choose your gender:</strong>
<form name="genderForm">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Sir" />
    Male
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Ma'am" />
    Female
  </label>
</form>
```