# Execute php script from onclick insert to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a working example that inserts the value of a radio button to a database using a submit button but now i'm looking at ways to insert without the use of a submit button.

I have a javascript function that when a radio button is clicked it should execute the php.

I have looked at why i can't get it to function but i'm unsure if its even possible or if there's a better way to do this. Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>survey</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<div class="cc-selector">
      <form class="cc-selector" id="form-id"  method="POST">
    <label><input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="doSomething();"></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy"></label>
    <label><input id="sad" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="doSomething();"></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc sad"for="sad"></label>
  </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function doSomething() { 
    $.get("sample2.php"); 
    return false; 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my php sample2.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  if (isset($_POST['radioAnswer'])){
        $radioAnswer = $_POST['radioAnswer'];
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO survey (radioAnswer) VALUES ('$radioAnswer')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript jquery radio button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142300/javascript-jquery-radio-button-click)

Comment: In your javascript, you have `$.get()`. In your php, you have `$_POST`. See the problem? Protip: you always post forms.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You're actually not sending any data.

Answer (score 0):

Use onchange. and an opening body tag.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>survey</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="cc-selector">
      <form class="cc-selector" id="form-id"  method="POST">
    <label><input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onchange="doSomething();"></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy"></label>
    <label><input id="sad" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onchange="doSomething();"></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc sad"for="sad"></label>
  </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function doSomething() { 
    $.get("sample2.php"); 
    return false; 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are preforming database insert in a GET request,

First, this is very bad practice.

Second, it won't work as expected because GET request could be cached by browser or proxies,

Btw, your PHP is reading $_POST

Answer (score 0):

send requests using ajax javascript

```js
function doSomething() { 
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'radio1': $('#happy').is(':checked'), 'radio2': $('#sad').is(':checked')}
        url: '/your_php_file_name.php',
        success: function(data){
          console.log("here is the result : " + data);
        }
      }
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cc-selector">
      <form class="cc-selector" id="form-id"  method="GET>
    <label><input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="doSomething();"></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy"></label>
    <label><input id="sad" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="doSomething();"></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc sad"for="sad"></label>
  </form>
        </div>
```

in your your_php_file_name.php file

```
<?php
    // your javascript radio button 1 value;
    $happy = $_GET('radio1');
    // your javascipt radio button 2 value ;
    $sad = $_GET('radio2');
    echo 'success';
?>
```

Comment: Running the Snippet you get a error {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 26,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: you should replace your_php_file_name.php from the file name of your php file

Answer (score 0):

The $.get() method requests data from the server with an HTTP GET request.
what you want to do is send data from the server using an HTTP POST request.
i suggest you use :

```
    $.post("sample2.php",
{
    name: "Donald Duck",
    city: "Duckburg"
},
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

or even better :

```
    $.ajax({
   url : 'sample2.php',
   type : 'POST', 
   data : 'email=' + email + 'content=' + content,
   dataType : 'html'
});
```

find more details about $.ajax in https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to execute my Php using the onclick method to insert into sql database answer below.

```
 <form name="form" action="sample2.php" class="cc-selector" method="post" >

       <label class="label">
        <input type="image" name="Opinion" value="Positive" src="happy.png" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"/>

       </label>

       <label class="label">
        <input type="image" name="Opinion" value="Negative" src="sad.png" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"/>
       </label>
      </form>
```