# How to activate event on clicking radio button by id?

Tags: javascript, css

I wish to fire an event on selecting particular radiobutton by its id. Not able to get it working and any suggestion would be highly appreciated

```js
if (event.target.id === "alarmManagRadios2") {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="radio" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios1" value="ALARM" checked="">
  <br>
  <div for="alarmManagRadios1">
    Alarm
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios2" value="TEST">
  <br>
  <div for="alarmManagRadios2">
    Test
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("alarmManagRadios2").addEventListener("click", () => alert("hi"));`

Comment: There's some javascript missing here. How do you attach the click listener ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142300/javascript-jquery-radio-button-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the radio button and iterate over the collection and add event to it. On change check for the id of the clicked element.

`document.getElementsByName` will give a collection and to use array method `forEach` `...` is used

```js
[...document.getElementsByName('alarmManagRadios')].forEach((item) => {

  item.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (event.target.id === "alarmManagRadios2") {
      alert("hi");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios1" value="ALARM" checked="">
<br>
<div for="alarmManagRadios1">
  Alarm
</div>
<input type="radio" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios2" value="TEST">
<br>
<div for="alarmManagRadios2">
  Test
</div>
```

You can also use `Array.from` if browser support it

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByName('alarmManagRadios')).forEach((item) => {

  item.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (event.target.id === "alarmManagRadios2") {
      alert("hi");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios1" value="ALARM" checked="">
<br>
<div for="alarmManagRadios1">
  Alarm
</div>
<input type="radio" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios2" value="TEST">
<br>
<div for="alarmManagRadios2">
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call a function onchange of radio passing the element itself and in the function compare with the id of radio button

```js
function a(ele)
{
console.log(ele)
if (ele.getAttribute('id') === "alarmManagRadios2") {
  alert("hi");
}

}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="radio" onchange="a(this)" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios1" value="ALARM" checked="">
  <br>
  <div for="alarmManagRadios1">
    Alarm
  </div>
  <input type="radio"  onchange="a(this)" name="alarmManagRadios" id="alarmManagRadios2" value="TEST">
  <br>
  <div for="alarmManagRadios2">
    Test
  </div>
</body>
```