# text box to open when "no" radio button selected and must be reuired to continue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, adobe, custom-wordpress-pages

I am desperate for help. I have a yes and no radio button. The No radio button needs to open a hidden text box that needs to be completed to continue of the form. I am absolutely new to html and have no idea how to complete this.

Comment: Similar questions were asked here. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142300/javascript-jquery-radio-button-click

Answer (score 1):

For example it can be done this way:

```js
function submitForm() {
  if (document.forms["form"]["no"].checked && document.forms["form"]["noTextarea"].value == "") { // If No option checked and if textarea´s value is empty ("")
    alert("If checked No, textarea must be filled.");
    return false;
  }
  else if (document.forms["form"]["yes"].checked == false && document.forms["form"]["no"].checked == false) { // If nothing is checked
    alert("Nothing was checked. You must select Yes or No.");
    return false;
  }
  else if (document.forms["form"]["yes"].checked) { // If checked Yes
    alert("Form OK.");
  }
  else { // Else (if checked No and textarea filled
    alert("Form OK.");
  }
}

function showTextarea() {
  if (document.forms["form"]["no"].checked) {
    document.forms["form"]["noTextarea"].style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    document.forms["form"]["noTextarea"].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
  <input type=radio name=yesnoRadio id=yes onclick=showTextarea()>
  <label for=yes>Yes</label>

  <input type=radio name=yesnoRadio id=no onclick=showTextarea()>
  <label for=no>No</label>

  <br>
  <textarea id="noTextarea" style="display: none;" placeholder="Requied when selecting 'No'"></textarea>

  <br>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```